# ImageIO error when writing to file

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsdata, javax.imageio, writetofile

I am trying to save a UIImage but it gives me an error. The UIImage is picked from the UIImagePickerController and is then saved by making an `NSData` out of it and call `writeToFile:` on this `NSData` object.
When doing so, I will get an error. The same method stores other images perfectly. The images which I have no problem storing retrieved from a website as a byte array and is then converted to a UIImage and is then saved.
It seems that the issue is specific for images from the `UIImagePickerController`.

Can anybody tell me how I can fix this?

It seems that the images from the `UIImagePickerController` is saved fine but I still get this error which causes the application to crash:

> May  1 10:38:05 Simon-BS-iPhone Diims[619] : ImageIO: JPEG
>   Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment

This is the code used to save the image:

```
+ (void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image name:(NSString *)name
{
    NSString *pathForCache = [self pathForCache];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
    NSString *jpegPath = [pathForCache stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg", name]];

    NSError *error;
    if ([imageData writeToFile:jpegPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error] == NO)
    {
        DLog(@"Could not save image: %@", jpegPath);
        DLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}
```

It is called like this when an image is selected:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    // Close controller
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Save image
    self.selectedDevice.image = image;
    [CDeviceManager localUpdateDevice:self.selectedDevice delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Try changing your code as  follows if it works:-  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
   
    // Save image
    self.selectedDevice.image = image;
    [CDeviceManager localUpdateDevice:self.selectedDevice delegate:self];    // Close controller
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}   //dismiss after saving the image

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thank you, very much. Could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: hi SimonBS,I have posted the same as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code as follows if it works:-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
 {
       // Save image self.selectedDevice.image = image;
       [CDeviceManager localUpdateDevice:self.selectedDevice delegate:self];

       // Close controller [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
       //dismiss after saving the image
  }
```